# NodeEntity cant be cast to graphdb.Node

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I have a NodeEntity like the following and I want to use Pathfinder algorithm on it. The algorithm is below. unfortuantely I get the error that neo4j.entity.Stop cannot be cast to org.neo4j.graphdb.Node

What should I do? I dont know how to make spring use the org.neo.graphalgo graphalgo library

```
private Path testGraphAlgoFactory(Stop s1, Stop s2){

 PathExpander expander = PathExpanders.allTypesAndDirections();

 PathFinder<Path> pathFinder =
                GraphAlgoFactory.shortestPath(expander , 6);

 Path path = pathFinder.findSinglePath((Node)s1, (Node)s2);
}
```

This is my NodeEntity class as follows:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Stop {
    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Property(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Property(name="lon")
    private double longitude;

    @Property(name="lat")
    private double latitude;

    @Property(name="id")
    private String stopId;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using OGM to convert the nodes from the graph into objects this is a valid outcome. 
The classes like `Stop` are "just" Java classes and do not know that they have any Neo4j origin.

Besides this (and also regarding you other question from earlier this day): the graph algorithms are intended to be used as a plugin in Neo4j and not as part of your application code. [Neo4j Graph Algorithms documentation](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-graph-algorithms/#_installation)

So it might be easier in your application to use the `SessionFactory` and get a new `Session` to run a cypher statement that calls the algorithm on your Neo4j. e.g. `CALL algo.shortestPath(...)`

Another option could be that you use a custom query in your SpringData Neo4j repository to execute the query statement by using `@Query("CALL ...")`. But you must know what you will return from your cypher statement. Then you can put the result into a `@QueryResult` class. [Sample from the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#reference_programming-model_mapresult) (but do not create an inner class but a class in your entity scan path)

Comment: wow man. Thanks a lot. I am quite new to Neo4j and your answer has cleared so many of my doubts. I exactly know what I have to do.